# How to stop and start arangodb server in arangodb docker container

Tags: arangodb

I could not stop the arangodb server in arangodb docker container.

when I execute below one,

$/etc/init.d/arangod stop

$service arangodb status

- arangod is not running

But I could still connect arangodb server using arangosh.

I don't know why this is happening , Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the ArangoDB web interface select the support option from the left.  Then select the "Rest API" tab and scroll down to the "/_admin/shutdown" option.  On the right of this click on the "Initiate shutdown sequence" link.  This opens an area that has a button labeled "Try it out!".  Pressing this button will shut down your server.

I am using the V3.2.4 Community Edition.

Answer (score 4):

ArangoDB is now [available via the Docker library](https://hub.docker.com/_/arangodb/)

The ArangoDB 2.8.x docker container will only run the ArangoDB service alone.

you can use

```
docker ps -a
```

to get the container ID (and its started/stopped state), which you then can use with

```
docker start <container ID>
```

and

```
docker stop <Container ID>
```

to start/stop the ArangoDB server.

```
docker exec -it <Container ID> bash
```

can give you a shell inside of that running container, but the user is not privileged to start or stop the service.